# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found with zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I hope someone can help me with this.

I am working my way through Rob Allen's Zend Framework 2 Tutorial .

When I try to go to:

http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album
I get the following error in apache's log (i using Zend Server CE version free):

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 175

module\Album\module.config.php

```
<?php
 return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController'
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
        )
       )
  );
```

module\Album\src\Album\Controller\Albumcontroller.php

```
<?php
 namespace Album\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

 class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $albumTable;
public function getAlbumTable()
{
    if (!$this->albumTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
    }
    return $this->albumTable;
}
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function addAction()
{
}

public function editAction()
{
}

public function deleteAction()
{
}
}
```

My configuration:

Windows xp.
Zend Server CE Technology Preview (PHP 5.3).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you configured the autoloader? (For instance, `getAutoloaderConfig()` in the Module class.)

Comment: yes, i have.
public function getAutoloadConfig(){
   return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );

Comment: Oh my god. getAutoloaderConfig() not getAutoloadConfig(), it's work. Thank for your help!